# How to filter only cluster-admin roles in kubectl command

Tags: kubernetes

I am using "kubectl.exe get clusterrolebindings" command to list all cluster rolebindings. i am interested in data for 'cluster-admin' role.

How do i filter that and dump into json file. ?.

C:\Users\abcd>kubectl.exe get clusterrolebindings
NAME                                                   ROLE                                                                               AGE
aks-aad-pod-id-nmi-binding                             ClusterRole/aks-aad-pod-id-nmi-role                                                58d
aks-cluster-admin-binding                              ClusterRole/cluster-admin                                                          58d
aks-secretproviderclasses-rolebinding                  ClusterRole/aks-secretproviderclasses-role                                         58d
bigcat-cluster-admins                                  ClusterRole/cluster-admin                                                          58d

Answer (score 0):

There are few kubectl plugins that can handle RBAC reporting. Take a look at the [krew](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/plugins/) plugin page to get a full list:

- https://github.com/aquasecurity/kubectl-who-can
- https://github.com/corneliusweig/rakkess
- https://github.com/jasonrichardsmith/rbac-view

to name a few

Comment: Thanks, Jonathan. i can not use this plugin as i will issue this command to API as Runcommand. so i need to use some regular expression filter and get the result in JSON format